# Running a loop to add a variable into pathname to create folders

Tags: excel, vba, directory

I have two columnns , Country and business. There a 4 types of businesses possible in each country (mining, trucking, shipping, flights), and each country has atleast one business eg

```
Country  | Business
---------------------
England     mining
England     trucking
Spain       mining
Germany     mining
Germany     trucking
Germany     shipping
Germany     flights
```

There are around 170+ countries for which i have folders. I need to create folders in each country for the particular businesses it has. Im having a problem with the path. here is part of the code .Am i going in the right direction?

```
Dim z As Integer
Dim row,col,c As String


ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Select

For row = 2 To maxrows
col = 2
z = col + 1
c = Cells(row, col)


If Len(dir("C:\Users\patelwa\Documents\macr\& c &" & Cells(row, z), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
MkDir ("C:\Users\patelwa\Documents\macr\& c &" & Cells(row, z))

On Error Resume Next
End If
Next row
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I see about the path is that:

1. You try to concatenate inside the string: `"C:\Users\patelwa\Documents\macr\& c &"`
2. I'm not sure `"\"` and `"/"` is exactly the same (I didn't tested) ... you may need to test that too. As @hnk said, maybe you can use

> Application.PathSeparator (which becomes "/" or "\" depending on the
>   system (Windows, Mac, etc.)

1. You forgot a `"/"` between `c` and `Cells(row,z)`

Try this code (you may need to adapt it a little)

```
Dim z As Integer
Dim row,col,c As String
Dim foldername As String

ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Select    ' I don't get the point of that line

For row = 2 To maxrows

    col = 2
    c = Cells(row, col)

    foldername = "C:/Users/patelwa/Documents/macr/" & c & "/" & Cells(row, col+1)

    If Dir(foldername, vbDirectory) = "" Then                   

        MkDir (foldername)
        On Error Resume Next

    End If

Next row
```

Just an optimization tip: Avoid `.Select` if it's not really needed. But maybe you use it here to go back to the top left corner (in order to see the datas)

**NOTE:** This code assume that the country names match the folder names ... you may also need to test the country folders currently exist: If not you will get an error (catched by `On Error Resume Next`)

You can add before the `if` something like

```
If Dir("C:/Users/patelwa/Documents/macr/" & c, vbDirectory) = "" Then

   MkDir ("C:/Users/patelwa/Documents/macr/" & c)
   ' On Error Resume Next  ' If you want to use that ...

End If
```

to create the country folder if needed.

**Last note:** Check you do not have spaces or special characters in the cells used for the folder names (But I imagine you already checked)

Comment: Thank you. Was a big help. The "\" is correct in windows.. The "&"s and the "\"s in the path were confusing me as to where to put them when adding a variable into a path to run through a loop to check in each folder. You set me on right path to solution